# no puedo ejecutar mi proyecto localhost en mi navegador creado en C#

Tags: javascript, html, c#

tengo un proyecto en html y js, me dijeron que tenia que crear un navegador Web en C# y poder ejecutar mi proyecto localhost, el problema es que esta generando problemas con los scripts del proyecto, alguien tiene conocimiento de como se pueda solucionar ese problema?

este es mi navegador web el front montado en un proyecto windows form en C# VS2019

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el unico codigo que tengo en el C#

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
        }

        private void abrirToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private void atrasToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoBack();
        }

        private void adelanteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoHome();
        }

        private void actualizarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Refresh();
        }
```

en el html  tengo un login sencillo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Mangoo</title>
    <link href="Recursos/bootstrap-5.2.0-beta1-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Section Scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Recursos/bootstrap-5.2.0-beta1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="bg-grey">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="contenedorprincipal">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="prueba">
                    <h4 class="mt-4">Inicio de sesión</h4>
                    <form id="loginForm" class="form-container">
                        <div class="form-floating">
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" id="usuario" class="form-control my-3" required autofocus>
                          <label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating input-group">
                            <input id="Password" type="password" Class="form-control" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a">
                            <i class="bi bi-eye-slash" id="togglePassword"></i>
                            <label for="password">Contrase&ntilde;a</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mt-3">
                          <button class="btn btn-ingreso" id="btningresar"> INICIAR SESIÓN</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <label>Aún no tienes una cuenta de Mangoo? </label><a href="index.php?register=1" id="create-account"> Create una nueva cuenta</a>
                    </div>
                    <center><a href="#"><img src="Img/Logo.png" class="imagenlogo"></h1></a></center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

y este es el js

```
$("#btningresar").on("click", function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(($('#usuario').val() == '') == true){
        $('#usuario').focus();
    }else if(($('#password').val() == '') == true){
        $('#password').focus();
    }else{
        var parametros = {
            "usuariologin" : $('#usuario').val(),
            "passwordlogin" : $('#password').val(),
        }
        var Url = window.location.href;
        var win = window.open(''+Url+'home.html', '_self');
        win.focus();
    }
});
```

pero en mi navegador no funciona absolutamente nada del js

Comment: De la [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=windowsdesktop-8.0): *Para los nuevos proyectos de Windows Forms, se recomienda usar el control [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/microsoft-edge/webview2/) de Microsoft Edge en lugar del WebBrowser control .* Te aconsejo usar WebView2 que te permitirá ejecutar el código JS sin tantos problemas. Saludos

Comment: Hola Mauricio gracias por su consejo, voy a hacer el cambio a ver que tal

Comment: Mauricio muchas gracias, ese webview2 si funciona sin problemas algunos.

Comment: Puedes responder tu propia pregunta, agrega los detalles de cómo pudiste solucionar el problema, no es necesario copiar todo el programa, sólo la parte escencial del cambio realizado. Si adjuntas link a la documentación es un plus. Luego, pasadas 24 horas de haber publicado tu respuesta  podrás aceptarla como válida haciendo clic en el checkmark ✅

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tome el consejo de mauricio, utilice webview2

aca  les dejo el video con el que me guie, este si lee los scripts sin problema

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4U1BucVOCU&ab_channel=RubenHidalgoCarrillo

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]